# Which constructs in TeX/LaTeX and their packages have classification \mathinner?

Tags: math-mode

**Which constructs in (La)TeX and (La)TeX packages have classification `\mathinner`?**

The TeXbook mentions:

- fractions
- `\left...\right` constructions
- `\ldots`, `\cdots`, `\ddots`

Which fractions - all? Do other frequently used packages (e.g. AMS-LaTeX) define other constructs (e.g. I'm assuming all types of triple dots in AMS-LaTeX)?

One might expect the following to generate `\mathinner`, but they don't:

- `\bigl...\bigr` (and the larger-size analogues)
- `\lvert...\rvert`

Comment: There's no reason why `\bigl...\bigr` should be inner, nor `\lvert...\rvert`.

Comment: @egreg 1. You can think of them as an instantiation of `\left...\right`, which in effect reduces to one of the `\σl...\σr`-sizes. 2. A user might not know that `\σl` and `\σr` don't need to be paired.

Answer (score 7):

`amsmath` defines `\@cdots` as `\mathinner`; this in turn is used for `\cdots`, `\dotsi`, `\dotsb`, `\dotsm`and `\intdots`.

`\mathellipsis` and `\ddots` are so defined in `fontmath.ltx`.

`mathtools` doesn't add anything obvious.

i don't claim this list is complete.